# How to dynamically create a datagrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have the following datagrid in XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding View}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"
          GridLinesVisibility="None" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
          CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" 
          CanUserReorderColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Width="200" FontSize="12" 
                            Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ingredients" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Ingredients}" 
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"
                            GridLinesVisibility="None" CanUserAddRows="False" 
                            CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                            CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" >
                        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ingredients" 
                                            Width="*" FontSize="12"
                                            Binding="{Binding Path=IngredientName}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantite" Width="*" 
                                          FontSize="12" Binding="{Binding Path=Qty}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I am trying to find a way to create the datagrid dynamically (in-code) so that I can create multiple copies of it and bind it to different datasources at run-time.

Is this possible?  Anyone know how I could go about it for a datagrid complicated like this?

Comment: Why would you like to creat copies of the data grid? Just change the dataSource at run time

Comment: I need to show MANY grids

Comment: @JScwartz is the number of grids decided at run time by user action ? or its just many grids but const number?

Comment: @makc Decided at run-time but not by the user, by the amount (# of rows) of data I get from the DB at load at any particular time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, move as much as possible of the different settings out into reusable `Styles` and `DataTemplates`, leaving very little in the DataGrid itself:

```xml
<UserControl ... >
  <UserControl.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="GridHeaderStyle" 
         TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
     <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
  </Style>
  <Style x:Key="ReadOnlyGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" >
      <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
      <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
      <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="None" />
      <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False" />
      <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False" />
      <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="False" />
      <Setter Property="CanUserResizeRows" Value="False" />
      <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False" />
      <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" 
              Value="{StaticResource GridHeaderStyle}" />
  </Style>

  <DataTemplate x:Key="IngredientsCellTemplate">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Ingredients}" 
               Style="{StaticResource ReadOnlyGridStyle}">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ingredients" Width="*" 
                         FontSize="12"
               Binding="{Binding Path=IngredientName}" />
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantite" Width="*" 
                         FontSize="12"
               Binding="{Binding Path=Qty}" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

 <!-- A DataGrid using our Styles: -->
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding View}" 
          Style="{StaticResource ReadOnlyGridStyle}" >
  <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" 
       Width="200" FontSize="12"
       Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
     <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ingredients" 
       Width="*"
       CellTemplate="{StaticResource IngredientsCellTemplate}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

Then it gets a lot easier to create new DataGrids in your code-behind, using the existing Styles:

```
var datagrid = new DataGrid();
datagrid.Style = FindResource("ReadOnlyGridStyle") as Style;

datagrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
{
    Header = "Type",
    Width = new DataGridLength(200),
    FontSize = 12,
    Binding = new Binding("Name")
});
datagrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTemplateColumn()
{
    Header = "Ingredients",
    Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star),
    CellTemplate = FindResource("IngredientsCellTemplate") as DataTemplate
});

datagrid.ItemsSource = ...
```

Comment: I am having issues with the line Binding = new Binding("Name") as this is generated a compilation error: Error 3 The type or namespace name 'Binding' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: At the very top in your code file you should see a few lines like this: `using System...`. Add this line to that list: `using System.Windows.Data;`