# WPF: TabControl and dynamic TabItems

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I am trying to create a GUI for my current project using WPF in C#.
I would like to have tabs (dynamically created at runtime) and each tab should open a table with the same column headers but different contents.

I know I could realize tabs and tables like this:

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl  x:Name="tabControl"  TabStripPlacement="Left">
        <TabItem Header="Example 1" x:Name="tabItem" >
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TagCollection.Tags}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tag" Binding="{Binding Tag}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" />                                              
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Example 2" x:Name="tabItem1" >
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TagCollection.Tags}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tag" Binding="{Binding Tag}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </TabItem>

    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

How can I produce a view like that with code behind? I am not used to Bindings and such things yet, so perhaps someone could show me a short example?

Thanks
KatZe

Comment: Do a little googling on "MVVM TabControl" ... that should help you get going. MVVM will make this very easy once you get it going.

Answer (score 12):

I have create a sample project DynamicTabs.
Some sample context in constructor:

```
var tabs = new ObservableCollection<MyTab>();
int tabsCount = 5;
for (var i = 1; i <= tabsCount; i++)
{
    var tab = new MyTab() {Header = "Tab " + i};
    tab.Data.Add(new MyTabData() {Column1 = "col1" + i, Column2 = "col2" + i, Column3 = "col3" + i});
    tabs.Add(tab);
}
DataContext = tabs;
```

Classes for sample context:

```
public class MyTab
{
    public string Header { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<MyTabData> Data { get; } = new ObservableCollection<MyTabData>();
}

public class MyTabData
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public string Column3 { get; set; }
}
```

And XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DynamicTabs.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DynamicTabs"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:MyTab">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:MyTab">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1" Binding="{Binding Column1}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 2" Binding="{Binding Column2}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 3" Binding="{Binding Column3}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

ItemTemplate is for Header part of TabPage and ContentTemplate for Content of each TabPage.

Comment: thanks this works good! the only problem that is left is that there are created all columns 2 times now. First with Header names and second with Binding names

Comment: @Kat Ze, use property AutoGenerateColumns="False"

Answer (score 2):

Please Refer Following Links :

1. [Add/Remove Tabs Dynamically in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493538/Add-Remove-Tabs-Dynamically-in-WPF)
2. [How to dynamically create a datagrid in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120010/how-to-dynamically-create-a-datagrid-in-wpf)
3. [Set WPF TabControl to show the same Content for every tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350528/set-wpf-tabcontrol-to-show-the-same-content-for-every-tab)

Answer (score -1):

With some minor updates to your code-behind, you should be able to do this with :

```
<TabControl  x:Name="tabControl"  TabStripPlacement="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TableCollection}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourTableType}">
          <TabItem Header={Binding TableName}>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tag" Binding="{Binding Tag}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
          </TabItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Simply replace the properties in bindings according to your own needs.